# VSCODE - Code formatting in *.hbs files

Tags: handlebars.js, visual-studio-code

I have been using VS Code for a while now and I am loving it. But
there is a small problem with code formatting. It does not work in handlebars (`*.hbs`) files. This option is simply unavailable while editing hbs file.

I have tried '`Beautify`' extension, but it does not work properly for handlebars - it completely destroys the code.

Any help (or explanation of what am I doing wrong) on that topic would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Same issue applies to *.scss files. Can not format those either.

Comment: I have added an issue to vs code on github as this looks like a bug to me. You can follow it here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1735

Comment: Ok, thanks for reporting that.

Answer (score 15):

You can click in the bottom right corner on 'Handlebars' and change the language mode to HTML. Then the 'format code' option will be shown.

Comment: Thanks it helped and I could autoformat. Sadly it does not remember the setting for the file and it goes back to the auto-configured option when you reopen the file. :(

Comment: Go to the user settings via the file menu and add the following setting to persist your preference to handle *.hbs files as HTML files: 
`"files.associations": {
        "*.hbs": "html"
    }`

Comment: Not needed now. Update 1.15 released yesterday includes a theme for handlebars templates in Ember called 'Ember Frost'. It's friggin awesome! Especially if you combine it with the icon infiniti pack :)

Comment: Is it not possible to format hbs files using the html formatter but still keep the file set to Handlebars so that you still have syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 8):

## To manually format code:

Let's say the `.hbs` file we're working on is a `.js` file.

- Click the file language option (right side down)

[image: file language option]

- Change the file language to `.js`

[image: file language to javascript]

- Click anywhere in the file
- Press  <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>

## To automatically format code on save:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd> to open user preferences
- Enter the following code in the opened settings file

```
    {
      "editor.formatOnSave": true,
      "html.format.enable": true,
      "html.format.indentHandlebars": true,
      "html.format.maxPreserveNewLines": 0
    }
```

- Save file

[Source](https://medium.com/@alonbukai/how-to-format-handlebars-in-vscode-26144e9feec8)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project's vscode settings. It should be in `.vscode/settings.json` (if it doesn't exist, you can create it manually) and update it with the following config:

```json
{
  "[handlebars]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "files.associations": {
    "*.hbs": "handlebars"
  },
}
```

everything should work fine afterwards.