# VSCode - JavaScript Snippets Inside Handlebars <script>

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, visual-studio-code

## Problem

In Visual Studio Code, within a Handlebars file, when editing JavaScript code inside a `<script>`, JavaScript snippets are unavailable.

## Goal

Use JavaScript snippets in this situation.

## Example

Say I am in a handlebars file, which has a `<script>` tag.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log('This is JavaScript code.');
</script>
```

When editing the code inside the `<script>` (i.e., when the cursor is between `<script>` and `</script>`), I would like to use my JavaScript snippets. But I cannot. The Handlebars snippets are available, not the JavaScript ones.

1. [image: VSCode Language Handlebars]
2. [image: Insert Snippet]
3. [image: Handlebars Snippets]

---

However, if I change the file language from "Handlebars" to "HTML", the JavaScript snippets become available.

1. [image: VSCode Language HTML]
2. [image: Insert Snippet]
3. [image: JavaScript Snippets]

*(The only change is the language selection; the cursor is in the same position.)*

---

For both language selections, JavaScript syntax highlighting is used for the `<script>` content.

- Handlebars:

  - [image: Handlebars Syntax Highlighing]
- HTML:

  - [image: HTML Syntax Highlighting]

---

When the file language is Handlebars, Handlebars comments are used. When HTML, JavaScript ones are used.

- Handlebars:

  1. [image: Add Line Comment]
  2. [image: Handlebars Comment]
- HTML:

  1. [image: Add Line Comment]
  2. [image: HTML Comment]

## Analysis

This example shows that, inside the `<script>` content:

1. When the file language is either Handlebars or HTML, JavaScript syntax highlighting is used.
2. When the file language is Handlebars, Handlebars snippets and comments are used.
3. When the file language is HTML, JavaScript snippets and comments are used.

To visualize these relationships:

```markdown
| File       | Highlights | Snippets   | Comments   |
| ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| Handlebars | JS         | Handlebars | Handlebars |
| HTML       | JS         | JS         | JS         |
```

VSCode uses JS syntax highlighting in both cases. Therefore, it recognizes that the content is JS in both cases.

Why, then, does it not use the recognized language's snippets and comments? Is this a configurable setting or a missing feature of VSCode's built-in Handlebars extension?

## Notes

This is Visual Studio Code 1.21.1 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.4.

There are my HTML and Handlebars settings:

```
{
    "html.format.indentHandlebars": true,
}
```

Related questions:

- [VSCODE - Code formatting in *.hbs files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433915/vscode-code-formatting-in-hbs-files?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding emmet support for *.hbs files in your user settings.

```json
{
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
      "handlebars": "html"
  }
}
```